# Rewriting URL for subdomain redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to pass through a list of pages to show them coming from subdomain

When a user enters this url in the browser

**xyz**.mydomain.com/

it should be passed though as

www.mydomain.com/level1/pageA?**subdomain=xyz**

and

**xyz**.mydomain.com/**innerpage_abc**?param1=123

as

www.mydomain.com/level1/**innerpage?dynamicparam=abc&param1=123&subdomain=xyz**

Comment: Will it be okay that the URL in browser becomes `www.mydomain.com/level1/...` ?

Comment: no, the subdomain url should not change in browser when rewriting

Comment: In that case you need to have mod_proxy enabled. Both of your domains are pointing to same DOCUMENT_ROOT and same Apache web server right?

Comment: yes, i have all subdomains redirecting to same ip in dns settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and mod_proxy. Then put this code in .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(xyz)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.com/level1/pageA?subdomain=%1 [L,P,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(xyz)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)param1=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^_]+)_([^/]+)/?$ http://www.mydomain.com/level1/$1?dynamicparam=$2&subdomain=%1 [NC,L,P,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks anubhava, i will get back to you tomorrow when i implement it on domain

Comment: there is one problem in the 2rd rewrite, the url is changing from `xyz.mydomain.com/innerpage...` to `http://www.mydomain.com/level1/...` on the browser

Comment: Well as you can see `P` (for Proxy) flag is there in both the rules so they both should behave same way. Is first working fine for you?

Comment: yes, the first one is working fine. the problem is in websphere commerce, it has its own seourlmapper for redirecting.

Comment: Well you haven't mentioned anything about any existing .htaccess code so far :) In any case that code that I provided should work in isolation however if you post your full .htaccess in your question then only I can suggest something to avoid conflicts.

Comment: the code was working fine for 2nd rewrite as well, the 2nd page's was 301 redirecting to another url in its java code and after fixing that both pages are working fine